# Undo Multiple Git Commits in a Row but Keep All Changes

Tags: git

I see many questions/articles describing how to undo **a** commit but keep the changes.  What if I have made multiple enthusiastic (read: ill-advised) commits, to the wrong branch?

Here is the situation in a picture:

`A -> B -> C`

All of these changes are on master branch.

`A` is the last time master branch was correctly in sync with remote.

`B` was a set of changes that I made.  The changes are good and I want to keep them, but committing them to master branch was a mistake.

`C` was another set of changes I made.  These were also committed to master.  Stupid!  I want to keep these changes, but also not on master.

How can I get master branch back to state `A` while keeping all the changes from both `B` and `C`, so that I can commit them all to a new feature-fix branch?

I want to see this:

`A -> (all changes from B and C as unstaged changes)`

**Note:** I have not pushed anything to remote yet so this is all safely in my local repo.

Comment: The existing answer (with `git reset`) is fine, but consider doing `git checkout -b new; git branch -f master <hash-of-A>` so as to create a new branch pointing to commit `C` and move `master` back to commit `A` without bothering with anything else at all. With this particular sequence you'll now be on the new branch, with `master` referring to commit `A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move your `HEAD` pointer back to `A`, which calls for the `reset` command:

```
git reset A
```

This form of `reset` ([`--mixed`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---mixed), the default) will take the changes that you "re-setted" over and leave them in your working directory while your `master` branch will point back to `A`.

So, after you run this command, a `git diff` should show the contents of `B` and `C`.

After this, you could move those un-staged changes over to a separate branch:

```
git checkout -b feature-fix
git add .
git commit -m "changes"
```